# uninitialized constant Aws::VERSION - Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, paperclip, spree

I'm trying to upload Spree images to S3. but I'm having trouble to do it.

I get this error:

```
   raise e
        end
        if Gem::Version.new(Aws::VERSION) >= Gem::Version.new(2) &&
           Gem::Version.new(Aws::VERSION) <= Gem::Version.new("2.0.33")
          raise LoadError, "paperclip does not support aws-sdk versions 2.0.0 - 2.0.33.  Please upgrade aws-sdk to a newer version."
        end
```

For my understood the `aws` version needs to be upper to 2.0.33, but as you can see, this is my `gemfile`

```
#aws
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3'
```

Also I don't have `gem` for `paperclip`. Need to add one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, "fixed it". It's a problem with paperclip and the latest version of aws.

There's two work around:

first:

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 3.0'
```

secod:

```
# config/initializers/aws.rb
Aws::VERSION =  Gem.loaded_specs["aws-sdk"].version
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep using `aws-sdk` **version > 3.0**

just add this in **`config/initializers/aws.rb`**

```
Aws::VERSION =  Gem.loaded_specs["aws-sdk"].version
```

If `aws.rb` does not exist create one!